# Angular, lista não é atualização depois de uma exclusão ou inserção

Tags: angular

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação com `angular` e um `api rest` em PHP. estou realizando um CRUD bem simples, apenas para aprender.

O meu problema é quando vou realizar um insert/delete e logo depois vou recuperar um get com todas as informações.
Tenho um gerenciamento de Categoria, quando salvo essa categoria via API ela não aparece na minha lista de categorias, o mesmo aparece quando excluo, ela não é excluida da minha lista de categorias. porém estou utilizando o postman para poder acompanhar todas essas requisições e elas são feitas de fatos.

Não sei, parece que tem algo que me impede de recuperar a lista atualizada.

Exemplo:
Tenho 10 categorias então excluo uma e mesmo assim continua exibindo 10, mesmo eu acessando minha api para recuperar os dados novamente. Caso eu de um reload depois de uns 30 segundos a outra categoria aparece

Código fonte:
**categoria-list.component.list** // O componente que é usado para exibir e excluir

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getList();
  }

  excluir(desc, id) {

    if (confirm("Deseja excluir a categoria " + desc + " ?")) {
      let index = this.getIndex(id);
      if (index == -1)
        alert('Não foi encontrado o index do código D:');
      else {
        let result = this.categoriaService.delete(id).
          subscribe(dados => { this.getList() },
            (error: any) => alert('erro'));
        //this.items = this.items.splice(index, 1);
        this.items = this.items.filter(item => item.id != id);
      }
    }
  }

  getIndex(id) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++)
      if (this.items[i].id == id)
        return i;
    return -1;
  }

  getList(page: number = 1) {
    this._compiler.clearCache();
    this.categoriaService.get(page, this.pesquisarValue)
      .subscribe(dados => { console.log(dados); this.exibeLista(dados) }, (error: any) => console.log(error));
  }

  exibeLista(dados) {

    console.log('Total de Itens: ' + dados.result.count);
    this.items = null;

    if (dados.result.count == 0) // Quantidade de itens retornados da consulta
      this.pages = null;
    else {
      if (dados.result.paginas == 0) // Quantidade de paginas
        this.pages = null;
      else {
        this.totalPages = dados.result.paginas;
        this.loadPages();
      }
      this.items = dados.result.item;
    }

    console.log("Quantidade: " + dados.result.count);
  }
```

**Categoria.service**

```
 insert(ObjJson) {
    /*console.log("Objeto");console.log(ObjJson);console.log("Caminho :"+Auth.url + this.nameClass);console.log("Token :"+Auth.token);*/
    if (ObjJson.id == null)
      return this.http.post(Auth.url + this.nameClass, ObjJson, { headers: { 'token': Auth.token } });
    else
      return this.http.put(Auth.url + this.nameClass + "/" + ObjJson.id, ObjJson, { headers: { 'token': Auth.token } });
  }

  get(page, descricao) {
    page='all';
    return this.http.get(Auth.url + this.nameClass + `?page=${page}&desc=${descricao}`, { headers: { 'token': Auth.token } })
      .pipe(map(response => { return response })) // or try  `response.json()` instead of `response` 
  }

  delete(id) {
    console.log(Auth.url + this.nameClass + "/" + id);
    return this.http
      .delete(Auth.url + this.nameClass + "/" + id, { headers: { 'token': Auth.token } });

  }
```

Lembrando que sempre quando eu executo um delete ou insert eu verifico no banco de dados e no postman e consigo visualizar que foi realizado de fato, até o get no postman fica certo, o problema é quando recupero no angular 6.

Comment: Voce tem que esperar o retorno do update ou delete pra fazer a nova chamada do get

Comment: Atualmente, a melhor abordagem para esta sua situação é utilizar ngrx onde seus dados ficam em uma STORE observable e seus componentes atualizam dados através desta store.

Outra forma de fazer, porém acho muito desorganizada e sujeita a bugs, seria utilizar BehaviorSubject  e seus componentes se inscreverem neles.

Comment: @EduardoVargas olhe como estou fazendo na minha função de delete eu só chamo a atualização dentro do método subscribe, e é nesse método que ele me retorna se o update ou delete foi realizado com sucesso

Comment: @duarbr então do jeito que eu fiz não funciona?

Comment: Funcionar funciona, mas você precisaria dar outro GET após fazer um INSERT, UPDATE ou DELETE, o que não seria muito eficiente. 

Eu recomendo que você estude Subjects, Behavior Subjects, (REDUX)  NGRX.

Comment: Então, esse é o problema, se do jeito que está funciona, porque ele não está limpando minha variavel itens ... acabei de criar um novo projeto somento com 1 componente, um formulario e em baixo uma lista dos itens salvos ... quando eu salvo um item eu faço um get e mesmo assim me é trazido os elementos errados

Comment: Este é o problema, você terá que fazer REFRESH (via get) nos dados (da API onde eles foram inseridos) e também subscribe passando o retorno para o componente ... não é uma boa prática conforme a aplicação cresce.